Closure of a set in Sorgenfrey topology
In a certain exercise I have been asked to say whether $0 \in \overline{A}$, where $A = (-\infty,0) \cup [1,3)$ and $\overline{A}$ is the closure of the set, in the Sorgenfrey topology, with basis $\beta = \{[a,b): a < b, a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. In the solution of the exercise, it says that $0 \notin \overline{A}$ because $[0,1)$ is an open set whose intersection with the original set is empty. Up to this point, everything seemed right to me, but I found that with my reasoning, I reached a contradiction. I claim that $0 \in \overline{A}$ because the complement of $A$ is $A^c = [0,1) \cup [3,\infty)$, which is open in this topology (Sorgenfrey topology is finer than the usual one). Therefore, $A$ is closed and $\overline{A} = A$ by definition. Therefore, $0 \in \overline{A}$. Why do I reach this contradiction? Both arguments seem correct to me.

Yes, $A$ is a closed set (and your proof of that assertion is correct). So, since $0\notin A$, $0\notin\overline A$.
I fail to see why you wrote “Therefore, $0\in\overline A$”.

I didn't expect it was as silly as that, I didn't notice. Thanks
